# Manipulating JSON with LoDash

Tags: javascript, json, underscore.js, lodash

I've just started working with Lodash, and am trying to average out any value (at the lowest level) that's an array. No matter what I try, the original JSON persists.

Do I need to build a brand new object and push everything into it? Why can't I simply manipulate it like I would an array?

```
function averageIt(mtcs) {

function jsonAvg(dataSet) {

  function avg(elmt) {
    var sum = 0;
    for( var i = 0; elmt[i]; i++ ){
        sum += parseInt( elmt[i], 10 );
    }
    return Math.round(sum/elmt.length * 100) / 100;
  }

  _.forEach(dataSet.json, function(day) {
    _.mapValues(day, function(n) {
      return _.isArray(n) ? avg(n) : n;
    });
  });

  console.log("JSON Averaged:", dataSet.json);

  return dataSet;
}

_.forIn(mtcs.dataSets, function(set) {
  set = jsonAvg(set);
});

console.log("Averaged Metrics:", mtcs);

return mtcs;
}
```

Regards
- - - Really Confused "Programmer"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, when you use `_.mapValues` is where the avg function is applied. But as you are using a map function, the result you set in the return is not stored anywhere, and the `dataSet.json` remains the same. You could do this:

```
_.each(dataSet.json, function(day, index) {
  dataSet.json[index] = _.mapValues(day, function(n) {
    return _.isArray(n) ? avg(n) : n;
  });
});
```

Supposing that `dataSet.json` is an array. If it is an object, you should not apply an `each` to it, but do something like `Object.keys(dataSet.json)` to convert its properties to an array.

Comment: Ahhh ok, thanks. So pretty much, anytime I have a return value, I need to make sure it's assigned to something. Originally when i did try assigning it, I used "day" instead of "dataSet.json[index]"... so that was also my problem lol. Thanks again Nachoooooo

Comment: Well not always, but yes for the map functions. Also, when using day it didn't work because you were replacing the value of that temporal variable. However, using dataSet.json[index], you change the value of the dataSet.json variable, and so it persists. Just remind this, inside a forEach / map, if you want the data to persist, you need to do or the index trick or be able to do something like this:
_.each(dataSet.json, function(day, index) {
  day.hour = _.mapValues(day, function(n) {
...

i.e. A property inside the temporal variable, that way it also persists in the dataSet.json variable.